# Is "pause" event called on any kind of audio stop?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

MDN says:

> The pause event is sent when a request to pause an activity is handled
> and the activity has entered its paused state, most commonly after the
> media has been paused through a call to the element's pause() method.

But what if the audio stops because it stalled, or on an ended event.

Would it still trigger the `pause` event? Or should I also perform actions on `stalled` and `ended`?

Comment: The latter would be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Audio Pause Event**

The answer is that the pause event is only emitted after the `pause()` method is called or BEFORE an `ended` or `seeking` event. The seeking event happens when the track position is changed, which causes the player to toggle between pause and play.

The pause event is NOT emitted following a `stalled` or `waiting` event because the audio is still in a play state.  Also, when the audio src is changed it stops the player, but no pause event is emitted.

The [w3.org event specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-track-element.html#mediaevents) don't provide much detail and implementation may vary by browser.

**Run the code snippet to monitor audio events on your browser.**

```js
"audioprocess,canplay,canplaythrough,complete,durationchange,emptied,ended,loadeddata,loadedmetadata,pause,play,playing,ratechange,seeked,seeking,stalled,suspend,timeupdate,volumechange,waiting".split(",").forEach(name => {
  player.addEventListener(name, (e) => monitor.innerHTML= e.timeStamp.toFixed(2) + ": " + e.type + "\n" + monitor.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<small>Click the audio controls to monitor events:</small><br/>
<audio id="player" controls preload="false" src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/Epoq-Lepidoptera.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>

<textarea id="monitor" rows=6 style="width:100%"></textarea>
```